# Number format PHP

Tags: php

I want show this number for example

100.258 -> 100.25

I try do it with `number_format("100.258",2,"."," ");` but it return me 100.00, how can I do it, really I try search on internet but nothing work.

Comment: This should work. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/102e470387713b4764bf2fc055004cccaba3e5d9

Comment: He needs to floor it )

Comment: @ReneKorss it work but I need .25 and it return 0.26

Comment: Okay. Understood. Then you need to use floor like many answers already say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you needed output.

```
$number =  100.258;
$roundedDown = floor($number * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: It work fantastic but It return me .26 and I need return 0.25

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. Please check. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c21a294ec982fb005e061020fdb04ab9e26a2428

It gives me 100.25 :)